# Authenticate with Python-requests on aspx based website

Tags: python, asp.net, beautifulsoup, request

I want to scrape data from the shipping page of our company logistics which based on ASP. I watched a lot of tutorial on Internet about `BeautifulSoup` and `Requests` library. But it isn't working as expected for me.

The login url is:

> https://portal-vesta.sequoialog.com.br/tms/LoginPortal.aspx

I wrote code in bash script and my login attempt worked, returns this message:

```
69|dataItem||<script type="text/javascript">window.location="about:blank"</script>|32|pageRedirect||/tms/HomePortal.aspx?Usu=1070rpr|
```

But in python, it is returning me this message:

```
b'69|dataItem||<script type="text/javascript">window.location="about:blank"</script>|21|pageRedirect||/TMS/LoginPortal.aspx|'
```

My code is:

```
with Session() as s:

        page = s.get(urls[0])

        get_ev_vs(page)

        payload = "Ajax=UpdatePanel1%7CButton1&Button1=ENTRAR&__ASYNCPOST=true&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTVALIDATION={}&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE={}&txtSenha={}&txtUsuario={}&txtUsuarioSolicita=".format(ev, vs, password, user)
        head = {
            'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'X-MicrosoftAjax': 'Delta=true',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'Accept': '*/*'
        }

        response = s.post(urls[0], data=payload, headers=head)

        payload = {}
        headers = {
          'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"',
          'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
          'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
          'DNT': '1',
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36',
          'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
          'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=' + s.cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"]
        }

        open_page = s.get(urls[1], data=payload, headers=headers)
        print(open_page.text)

def get_ev_vs(page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    global vs, ev
    vs = soup.select_one('#__VIEWSTATE')['value']
    ev = soup.select_one('#__EVENTVALIDATION')['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin

target = ['__VIEWSTATE', '__EVENTVALIDATION']

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0",
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        values = [soup.select_one('#{}'.format(x))['value'] for x in target]
        data = {
            "Ajax": "UpdatePanel1|Button1",
            "__LASTFOCUS": "",
            "__EVENTTARGET": "",
            "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
            "__VIEWSTATE": values[0],
            "__EVENTVALIDATION": values[1],
            "txtUsuario": "aaa",      #username should be here
            "txtSenha": "aaa",        #password too!
            "txtUsuarioSolicita": "",
            "__ASYNCPOST": "true",
            "Button1": "ENTRAR"
        }
        r = req.post(url, data=data)
        match = re.search(r'ScriptPath\|([^|]+db)\|', r.text).group(1)
        final = urljoin(url, match)
        r = req.get(final)
        print(r.text)


main('https://portal-vesta.sequoialog.com.br/tms/LoginPortal.aspx')
```

Comment: wow, that's awesome!!! thank you so much for this reply, i just removed match and final variable and works very fine! my error was include headers on post request, sounds so much better just

req.headers.update(headers)